# Electron opens additional window on startup

Tags: electron, electron-forge

This is the code that I'm running to make my app start on startup:

```
app.setLoginItemSettings({ openAtLogin: true });
```

This works but the problem is it is running an extra window of electron (see image).
[image]

How do I stop this? I am using electron-forge template.

Comment: could you provide more detailed code on this. I don't think that it's complete

Comment: the setLoginItemSettings is all I'm using for the startup, if I comment out that code, the app woin't launch on startup...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it now, this happens because I set the auto start-up to true when on development, which cases the electron to startup... I just disabled the electron startup on Windows Startup.

Comment: How can I do that , could you please explain more?

Answer (score 2):

- Go to

> Task Manager > Startup

- Select Electron, and then click **Disable** button (at bottom right corner).

[image: Task manager image]